# Why is attaching gdbserver to a native android app failing?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, gdbserver

I am developing a fully native application in using C++ and pure CMake as the build system - no Android Studio involved at all (proof of concept [here](https://github.com/Aftnet/CMakeAndroidApk))

The code builds, apk is generated and can be installed and run via ADB without issue but I cannot get gdbserver64 to attach to the process for debugging.

More details:

- App is built against SDK/NDK API level 30
- Attempting to debug on an Android 11 emulator instance without Google Play
- I can run adb root just fine
- Image already includes gdbserver and gdbserver64, attempting to use those
- Developer options and USB debugging enebled in emulator
- App has `android:debuggable="true"` in manifest

But every time I try `gdbserver64  :5039 --attach $(pidof my.app.id)`

I get `/bin/sh: <app_pid>: inaccessible or not found`

What am I missing? And no, I cannot just move to Android Studio - this is a cross platform project that needs to be buildable using only CMake.

Comment: May be useful: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/wrap-script

Answer (score 1):

According to my observation, this may be a bug of prebuilt gdbserver. It treats the parameter after --attach as a program name and tries to start it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer, but in similar configuration to yours I got same error message and unable to overcome this. For me, switching to lldb helped, see [e.g.](https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/main/documentation/building/android.md#debugging-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue. So I started `gdbserver64` in multi mode, then was able to attach certain process from client side.

Run app in Android Virtual Device and determine PID

```
 $ adb shell am start -n org.gradle.samples/.MainActivity
 $ adb shell ps | grep "org.gradle.samples"
 u0_a132        3341    258 12955920 158336 0                  0 S org.gradle.samples
```

Start gdbserver

```
 1|generic_x86_64:/ # gdbserver64 --multi :8700                                                                                               
 Listening on port 8700
```

Enable adb port forwarding:

```
 $ adb forward tcp:8700 tcp:8700 
 $ adb forward --list
 emulator-5554 tcp:8700 tcp:8700
```

Execute GDB (use `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/ndk/<version>/ndk_gdb`) and connect to gdbserver.

```
 $ gdb
 GNU gdb (Debian 10.1-1.7) 10.1.90.20210103-git
 ...
 For help, type "help".
 Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
 (gdb) target extended-remote 127.0.0.1:8700
 Remote debugging using 127.0.0.1:8700
 (gdb)
```

gdbserver confirmed that connection is established

```
 1|generic_x86_64:/ # gdbserver64 --multi :8700                                                                                             
 Listening on port 8700
 Remote debugging from host 127.0.0.1, port 41111
```

Back to gdb shell I attached debugger to process:

```
 (gdb) attach 3341
```